# Display POST data of a form in a modal

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, modal-dialog, lightbox

I have the following code:

**Form:**

```
<form action="test.php" onsubmit="addForm(event)" id="testeForm" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="payButton"  value="BUY">
    <input type="hidden" name="type" value="pgmType" />
    <input type="hidden" name="total" value="10.00" />
</form>
```

**Window modal (lightbox):**

```
<div class="dark-pay" close="dark-pay" style="display:none">
    <div id="loadiFrame" data="test.php"></div>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function addForm(event){   
    document.querySelector(".dark-pay").style.display = "inline";
    $('#loadiFrame').html('<iframe style="border: 0;width: inherit;" src="' + $("#loadiFrame").attr("data") + '"></iframe>'); 
}
```

**Content of test.php**

```
<?php

    $type = $_POST["type"];
    $total = $_POST["total"];
    echo "Type: ".$type." - Total: ".$total;

?>
```

I need the file **test.php** to be opened inside lightbox by `iframe`, already with `POST` data for printing.

I already tried using several examples available here on the site and could not implement any. As it is now, it opens the `modal` but redirects the user to the new tab instead of opening it in the `modal`.

This is a payment gateway, the customer clicks the buy button on the `form`, then the lightbox (modal) opens with the form data, and then redirects to the payment method using this data, all within the modal without leaving the page.

Inside the file **test.php**, I will need to create a redirect, I don't know if this will work within modal too.

Any ideas on how I can do this?

Comment: How your inputs from form get into the iframe ? It seems like your form is kinda fake.You would have to somehow save data in db and then restore... Your buy button opens only iframe with "data.php" result. You are not sending any data to it. Then your script that redirects propably use `window` property that refers to parent's window (that runs iframe). Point me if I am wrong, but I think thats not the best way to implement that kind of things. If you want to send data async(without refreshing a page) then you should prepare your own form that sends data to "paymentSystem" if it handles Async

Comment: I unfortunately don't have much knowledge to do this, can you give me some examples?

Comment: You have written that it is payment gateway. What kind of service are you trying to connect to ?

Comment: With the platform Mercado Pago: https://www.mercadopago.com.br/developers/pt/guides/payments/web-checkout/introduction

Comment: Its about grasping the concept.  This page explains the most the process for me https://www.mercadopago.com.br/developers/en/guides/payments/web-tokenize-checkout/receiving-payment-by-card/. You put their script into the form. They tokenize your card data then you send this token to your server(async or not) and using this token you make payment from the server, then you get response and you can show success or false to the end user. Its how I understand it

Comment: If you want to make it work without losing active window you need to do it asynchronous way. If you never heard about it try finding some tutorial about it.